# Call stored function without knowing the parameter names through vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle11g

Can some one suggest me how to call a **stored function** in oracle through vb.net.

From vb.net should i able to pass the values to arguments of that function without knowing the parameter names?

Example: I have a function,
Create or Repalce Function Func_Name(param1 Varchar2,param2 varchar2)

Inorder to call this function through vb.net, we need to give

parameterargs.paramtername="param1"

Is there anyway so that i cannot use the parameter name and call the function

Thanks in advance
Rupesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that we handled it was to open the Oracle DB up through an OleDbConnection, then call GetOleDbSchemaTable asking for the Procedure_Columns.

For example:

```
DataTable dtTable;

dtData = this.Connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedure_Columns, new object[] {null, null, sName, null});
foreach (DataRow theRow in dtData.Rows)
{
    // Columns available in the row include: 
    // column_name, data_type, type_name, precision, and scale
}
```

Then, if you need to execute it without valid parameters (for example, to get the columns it exposes) you could execute it using DbNull.Value for each parameter.

Also, I can't remember exactly how Oracle operates, but in SQL Server you need to include the namespace when executing the function (i.e. select * from dbo.fn_my_test()). Also, depending on how the function is structured, you may have to select from it instead of executing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use named parameters with Oracle.

When you create the parameterized query, try using question marks as a place holder:

```
Select col1, col2 From tablename Where col1 = ? and col2 = ?
```

Then, be sure to add the parameters to the command object in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the parameter names to call it.
You need to know the number and type of them
Adding parameter names to the call means you don't have to pass all of them and / or you can pass them in a different order to the signature of the SP.

Call it like a parameterised query.

PSEUDOCODE

```
int customer_ID = 786;
Command.CommandText = 'Exec SP_MYProc @MyVar';
Command.Parameters.Add(new Parameter('MyVar',DbType.Int,customer_ID));
Command.Exec
```

Comment: Thanks tony, but i have a stored function rather than a procedure... Does it makes any difference. It is giving me an error like "Function name is not a procedure or undefined"